# MySQL security group view permission query

Tags: mysql

I have a table of records that are only viewable by users with the correct group permission. The records may be viewable by multiple groups. Users may also be in multiple groups.

**record**

```
+----+-------------------+
| id |    record_data    |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | Some sample data  |
|  2 | More data         |
|  3 | Some more data    |
+----+-------------------+
```

**groups**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | description |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Group A     |
|  2 | Group B     |
|  3 | Group C     |
|  4 | Group D     |
+----+-------------+
```

**user**

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Levi |
|  2 | Bill |
|  3 | Sam  |
|  4 | Jen  |
|  5 | Amy  |
+----+------+
```

I have created lookup tables to match the record to the groups that have permission to view them. I have also created a lookup table that matched the users with the groups they are members of.

**record_group**

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | record_id | group_id |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 |         1 |        2 |
|  2 |         1 |        4 |
|  3 |         2 |        1 |
|  4 |         3 |        2 |
|  5 |         3 |        3 |
|  6 |         3 |        4 |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

So in the table above, record one is viewable by users in group 2 and 4. Record 2 is viewable by users in group 1, and record 3 is viewable by users in group 2,3 and 4.

**user_group**

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | user_id | group_id |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |       1 |        1 |
|  2 |       1 |        2 |
|  3 |       1 |        4 |
|  4 |       2 |        1 |
|  5 |       2 |        4 |
+----+---------+----------+
```

Above, User 1 is in group 1,2 and 4. User 2 is in group 1 and 4.

I am trying to create a query that will show all the records that a particular user has the correct group permissions to view. Example. I want to list all the records that user ID 2 can view and ignore the others.

The query for user 2 should return record 2,3 and 6

I need to do this in a single query as it will be plugged into an existing framework.

My understanding is that I can do this with the MySQL IN function but I cant seem to get it to work with two sets, example (Select id from member_groups) IN ()

So my Question, how do I build a MySQL query that selects all the records user one has permissions to view?

I'm sorry I cant provide more information or example query, I'm not sure how to start.

SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e40ee6/1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT record.id AS id, details from record 
LEFT JOIN record_group ON record.id = record_group.record_id
WHERE record_group.group_id IN (SELECT group_id from user_group WHERE user_id = 2)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e40ee6/12

Answer (score 0):

I would use only joins as conditions of the form `WHERE column IN (SELECT ... FROm other_table)` are not fully optimized in older versions (before 5.6 - 5.7):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    r.id, r.details 
FROM record AS r
  JOIN record_group AS rg ON r.id = rg.record_id
  JOIN user_group AS ug ON rg.group_id = ug.group_id
WHERE ug.user_id = 2 ;
```

or this (you may need to disable the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` sql mode setting):

```
SELECT  
    r.id, r.details 
FROM record AS r
  JOIN record_group AS rg ON r.id = rg.record_id
  JOIN user_group AS ug ON rg.group_id = ug.group_id
WHERE ug.user_id = 2 
GROUP BY r.id ;
```

This would also work but I wouldn't expect improved efficiency:

```
SELECT r.id, r.details 
FROM record AS r
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM record_group AS rg 
          JOIN user_group AS ug ON rg.group_id = ug.group_id
        WHERE ug.user_id = 2 
          AND r.id = rg.record_id
       ) ;
```

A composite index on `user_group (user_id, group_id)` would help any of these queries (including yours).